# How to copy file with spaces remotely using sftp

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote, sftp, filenames

I am trying to copy a file from windows 7 to linux debian using SFTP
Filename is **ba ck.bak**

I am using SFTP to remotely put file through windows command prompt
If filename is *back.bak* then command executes successfully

```
sftp> sftpc root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx -pw=XXXXX -cmd="put back.bak /tmp"
```

but if filename is *ba ck.bak*, i.e. with spaces error occurs
I had tried using

```
-cmd="put 'ba ck.bak' /tmp"
```

but doesn't work

I am using this file in a windows batch file, so I cannot execute by logging into sftp session and executing command there. I can also execute these commands through shell file, but I would not want to create new file each time.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I got the answer on my own. Instead of searching all over the internet, I checked the help for the command, and got the answer in the examples:

```
sftpc root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx -pw=XXXXX -cmd="put \"ba ck.bak\" /tmp"
```

Had to escape the qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

You must cancel out those spaces using '\'. So your command would be,

```
sftp> sftpc root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx -pw=XXXXX -cmd="put ba\ ck.bak /tmp"
```

That will make the shell not see the space in the file name.

Comment: I am sorry, but that doesn't work as expected. Terminates with "Invalid Command Option: /tmp"